# Why is this particular substitution made? ($y=tx$)

Tags: polynomials, solution-verification, complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

A problem in *Complex Numbers* (Andreescu, Andrica) involving a Complex  Equation & a "Substitution" technique :

> Let us solve the equation $z^3 = 18 + 26i$, where $z = x + yi$ and $x$, $y$ are
> integers.

Solution given :

> We can write $(x + yi)^3 = (x + yi)^2 \times (x + yi)$ = $(x^2 − y^2 + 2xyi)(x + yi)
> = (x^3 − 3xy^2) + (3x^2y − y^3)i = 18 + 26i$
>
> Using the definition of equality of complex numbers, we obtain
>
> $x^3 − 3xy^2 = 18$,
>
> $3x^2y − y^3 = 26$
>
>  Setting $\color{maroon}{y = tx}$ in the equality $18(3x^2y − y^3) = 26(x^3 − 3xy^2)$, let us observe
> that $x \ne 0$ and $y\ne 0$ implies
>
>  $18(3t − t^3) = 26(1 − 3t^2)$, which is equivalent to 
>  $(3t − 1)(3t^2 − 12t − 13) = 0$.
>
>  The only rational solution of this equation is $t=\frac{1}{3}$ ...

I'm not able to understand the rationale behind substituting $y=tx$.
I tried substituting $y=mx+c$ after differentiating both relations, but that leads nowhere ($1=1$, haha).

On thinking about it a bit more, I think it's because the relations are just changes of variables.
It is that $x^3 - 3xy^2$ would become $y^3-3x^2y$ when $x$ and $y$ are interchanged?
Is there some property accounting for this? If there is, could you please explain the rationale?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1934805/solve-the-equation-z3-1826i-where-z-xyi-and-x-y-are-integers?noredirect=1) (but not with the specific substitution)

Comment: The authors have basically just changed their goal from finding $x$ and $y$ to finding $x/y$, which is clearly easier to do here. I don't see how a substitution of the form $y=mx+c$ would help; that would just make this more convoluted.

Comment: @Sahaj So, this is just a technique to solve problems of a similar type? Thanks.

Comment: Yes and indeed a very popular trick. Thing to note here is that both equations can be divided by $y^3$ and you'll get terms in terms of $x/y$, which is when you divide both equations and are only left with $x/y$ to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Every Complex Number $z=x+iy$ can be put on the Complex Plane with Cartesian Coordinates $z=(x,y)$ & can written in Polar Coordinates like $z=(r,\theta)$.
Here $\tan(\theta)=y/x$ , which "Directly" gives us the "Substitution" in general scenarios.

We can check that the 2 equations will not let $x=0$ ( it will give $0=18$ ) & $y=0$ ( it will give $0=26$ )
Hence $\tan(\theta)=y/x$ is neither indeterminate nor $0$ nor $\infty$ here.
More-over , it is a real number in general , though it is a rational number in the given context.

Hence we take the Single Solution to the Cubic Equation which is the real number $1/3$ which is rational number too , according to the given context.
It means $z=3y+yi$ where $y$ is Non-Zero Integer.
We have to use this to get the overall Solution here.

[image: COMPLEX NUMBER]

When we use $z=3y+yi$ with $z^3=18+26i$ , we will get 3 Solutions , including the wanted Solution $z=3+1i$ , where the 2 Solutions will involve unwanted complicated values.